# How to select records using between restrictions in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I've tried using
input : 100 and 150
`criteria.add(Restrictions.between("price", from, to)));`
but result isn't between  100 - 150.
just getting 150.

I want it must retrieve 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, ...... 150.
So how to retrieve all records?

If two records has same price consider 102 then I want to retrieve them both.

BLManager.java

```
public List<Newitems> byPrice(Double from, Double to) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Newitems.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.between("price", BigDecimal.valueOf(from), BigDecimal.valueOf(to)));
    List<Newitems> newitems = criteria.list();
    session.close();
    return newitems;
```

client code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        BLManager manager = new BLManager();

        double from = 100;
        double to = 150;

        List<Newitems> newitems = manager.byPrice(from, to);
        Newitems nitems = newitems.iterator().next();
        System.out.println("Price of: " + nitems.getName() + " is " + nitems.getPrice());
    }
```

Comment: You may be getting the whole list but you are printing only one item in the main!! You need to loop through the newItems list and print all the items. Btw what is the size of newItems returned?

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank you so much.